# CSS Display: None & JS .show() break JQuery and AjaxToolkit Date Pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

So, I created a tabbed interface using java script, jQuery, and CSS in which I simply call .show() and .hide() on div's that contain a tab's contents. All of which works perfectly fine; however, one of the tabs requires the user of a Date Picker (I've tried this using both a jQuery and the AjaxToolkit DatePickers).

The date picker is attached to an input on the third tab, and will show when the box is pressed (as is expected) the first time I go to the third tab; however, subsequent times in which the third tab is shown, clicking on the date picker input simply has no effect.

The java script that controls the tabs is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize the first tab as selected
    $('#tabMenu > li:eq(0)').css('backgroundColor', '#E9E6D7')
    $('#tabMenu > li:eq(0)').addClass('selected');

    // hide all of the tabs but the first
    $('.tabBoxBody div').hide();
    $('.tabBoxBody div:eq(0)').show();

    // whenever a list item in the tab bar is clicked
    $('#tabMenu > li').click(function () {

        // make sure the tab isn't already selected
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {

            // remove selected from the old tab and add it to the new
            $('#tabMenu > li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            // hide the old tab's contents and show the new one's
            $('.tabBoxBody div').hide();
            $('.tabBoxBody div:eq(' + $('#tabMenu > li').index(this) + ')').show()

            // clear all background colors and set the new tab's color
            $('#tabMenu > li').css('backgroundColor', '#C2CBDA')
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#E9E6D7')
        }

    })
```

Any help or insight into why this is the case would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I have this kind of thing working in [a simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEY6w/). Could you edit it to be more like your situation in order to try to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.tabBoxBody div').hide();
```

I think this line affects the divs that form the datepicker.

You could add a class 'tab' to your div and then just

```
$('.tabBoxBody .tab').hide();
```

Comment: Yes, this managed to fix it. Thanks for the response. Although, curiously, I'm using ASP.net, and I had each tab's contents as a separate control file, but when I moved the third tab (the one with picker) into the main aspx file, it worked without this fix. This fix makes it work in both places though.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Do you know why changing the selector fixes it @Andrei? I would have thought it should behave identically... It's still selecting the same element, right?

Comment: @Ben Thanks. @Spycho The datepicker element jqueryui widget is made up of several divs. ".tabBoxBody div" would match all the divs inside the .tabBoxBody, _INCLUDING_ the divs of datepicker, but he only unhides '.tabBoxBody div:eq(' + $('#tabMenu > li').index(this) + '). Another solution would be to simply add the child selector, so the selector becomes ".tabBoxBody > div" which means select any first-level children divs from .tabBoxBody.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to rebind the date plugin to your input box each time you load the content in your tab.

Comment: Spycho is right. You only need to do that when you add new elements.